# cron.yaml not getting loaded for scheduling in AWS ElasticBeanstalk worker environment

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment for scheduling some jobs and  using Spring Boot to create JAR file.

As per the documentation we should put cron.yaml file in root of our application. I am putting cron.yaml file in top directory of Jar.

But cron.yaml not getting loaded and scheduling not working. Here is my cron.yaml

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "someJob"
   url: "/someJob"
   schedule: "* * * * *"
```

If I use Spring crons like `@Scheduled(cron = "${data.scheduler.cron}")` that works fine but I dont want to use that as I might have multiple workers in future to share load. Spring cron will run job on each worker

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I'm facing a similar problem.